# How to reduce the size of thumbsize of scrollbar

Tags: .net, wpf

I've a recording file whose size can be scrolled by a WPF scrollbar(value of scrollbar maximum and minimum is in milliseconds).

I've used a timer control which will keep on querying for the size of recoding file. Each second the size of recording file increases. It can go upto maximum for 12 hrs or a user can stop it in between.

My requirements are :

1. When we start the recording the thumbsize of scrollbar should be having the length of complete viewport(Scrollable area).
2. With progress of recording the thumbsize should decrease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default scrollbar gives you this functionality doesn't it? Just be sure to set the ViewportSize property on the ScrollBar.

The ScrollBar properties you need are

- Minimum: probably zero.
- Maximum: The current length of the recording.
- ViewportSize: The length of recording time that the viewport can see.

[image]

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="99" Width="418">

    <Grid Margin="0,0,2,0">
        <Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="1000" Name="slider1" Margin="61,27,0,0" Height="27" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="338" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider1}" Margin="10,32,0,0" Height="16" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="46"/>
        <ScrollBar Orientation="Horizontal"  Minimum="0" Maximum="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider1}" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="388" Height="1" SmallChange="1" LargeChange="10" ViewportSize="10"/>                                                                                                
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Should mark it as the answer if it helped you (shameless revisit of all answers given)